# CentOS: List the installed RPMs by date of installation/update?

Tags: rpm, centos, package-management

I'm on a CentOS machine. I updated and installed some packages a few weeks back, but I don't remember the name of every package or the names of every dependency. I used `yum`.

Can I list the packages on my system by the date they were last installed or updated?

Comment: This question (and the solutions) is probably generic to all RPM based Linux distros like Fedora, RHEL, CENTOS, and so on. I say probably just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To list all packages and their install dates, latest first:

```
rpm -qa --last
```

Comment: or the most recent 20 items which also show which sub version of RHEL (eg., 8.7.3): `rpm -qa --last | grep -E el8_[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]] | head -20`

Answer (score 26):

This should work on any RPM based machine:

```
rpm -qa --qf '%{INSTALLTIME} (%{INSTALLTIME:date}): %{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n' | sort -n
```

(To get a list of all possible tags, use `rpm --querytags`.)

Answer (score 0):

You might like the latest last:

```
rpm -qa --last | tac
```