# How do you list all files created by the user after a clean install?

Tags: linux, centos, package-management, configuration, rpm

I have a machine that is not in use and I wish to do a clean install of Linux on the machine. There may be important files on the machine.

**How do you list all files created by the user after a clean install?**

I was thinking of doing a simple find all files in `/` and then for loop to iterate followed by `rpm -q --whatprovides` to list all files that a user created (I.e not listed in any rpm's manifest). I think this would work... But it may be extremely slow and take more than 8 hours. I'll have to try.

I listed rpm but I think this also applies to any Linux distro... But I need a rpm solution first in the short term.

Answer (score 3):

`rpm -qla` will quickly list all the files coming from rpms. You can sort both lists and compare them with `comm`. However, what about config files from rpms that have been edited by the user, e.g. `/etc/exports`. You can use `rpm -qVa` to verify if installed files have changed, but it will ignore files that are destined to change e.g. `/etc/shadow`. It is usually a good idea to keep a copy of the whole of `/etc` just in case. You still have specific packages to worry about, e.g. mysql and files in `/var` ...

Comment: `comm`? Don't you mean `diff`? If you do mean `comm`, why?

Comment: `comm` is simpler than `diff`. `comm a b` will output 3 columns: lines only in a, only in b, and in common. The files must be sorted.  You can suppress the 2nd and 3rd column with `-23`, and so have immediately all the lines only in `a`, where you should in your case put the list from `find`.

Comment: i tried out `comm` and IMO it is definitely the way to go. it's exactly like you said `diff` could probably be used... but would require a huge effort to make the output useful... where as `comm` is immediately useful. in my case i did exactly as you said and suppressed two of the three columns.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways, depending on what you need:

- You could use the *ctime* (change-time) of files with the `find` command to find those which are recently changed, and from that the corresponding packages.  That can locate files which are not part of packages, e.g., if you find files under `/var`.
- You could use `rpm -qai` to get the install-dates for all packages, and obtain a report of those which were installed recently, and from that list, using `rpm -ql`, list the files for each package which were installed.

  For example, *[CentOS: List the installed RPMs by date of installation/update?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/centos-list-the-installed-rpms-by-date-of-installation-update)* points out that the `--last` option sorts the list from `rpm -qa` by date, and you would only have to filter the list to limit the packages according to when you did the initial install.