# Centos - List all install packages order by name

Tags: centos

I have two questions-

1. List all packages order by name
2. Search for a specific package that
   is intalled or not?

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and then learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CentOS: List the installed RPMs by date of installation/update?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2291/56041) and possibly [Different list of installed packages reported by rpm compared to yum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146159/56041). (But it is not clear you made an effort and had trouble due to differences; or made no effort).

Answer (score 0):

From `man sort`

> NAME         top
>
> ```
>   sort - sort lines of text files
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS         top
>
> ```
>   sort [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>   sort [OPTION]... --files0-from=F
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION         top
>
> ```
>   Write sorted concatenation of all FILE(s) to standard output.
>
>   With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
>
>  Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options
>   too.  Ordering options:
> ```

From `man yum`

> yum list installed [glob_exp1] [...]
>
> List the packages specified by args. If an argument does not match the name of an available package, it is assumed to be a shell-style glob and any matches are printed.

So,

1. To list all packages order by name

   ```
   yum list installed | sort
   ```
2. Search for a specific package that is intalled or not:

   I can not check this since I do not have a CentOS system at disposal, but    from man pages this should work:

   ```
   yum list installed $packageName
   ```

   What will return the result you look for is this:

   ```
   yum list installed | grep $packageName
   ```